# Getting a Cell Value from a Dropdown which contains the Sheet Name

Tags: excel

Say I'm on a neutral Sheet, but on a different sheet named "Sheet1" on Column B3 it has the Value "Hello".

I would simply type

```
='Sheet1'!B3
```

to get the value of B3 on that sheet.

But say on my neutral Sheet, I have a dropdown that contains the Sheet names in Column A1: "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"

You would think it would be

```
=A1!B3
```

but i get a

> ## REF1 Error 'Unresolved sheet name 'A1'

as it forces the single quotes around A1 so I can't seem to get the direct value of the dropdown.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `=indirect(chaR(39)&A1&"'!B3")`

Comment: @Jeeped hm it's saying Formula Parse Error

Comment: Try again. I had an extra quote in there.

Comment: @Jeeped hm same error on your edit

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B3")`?

Comment: @BruceWayne It worked!  thank you!

Comment: So you get that `CHAR(39)` is a `'` don't you?

Comment: @Jeeped no i didn't.. but it didn't work that way when u sing char?

Comment: Yes, it did. I tried it myself.